# I installed tensorflow in my python 3.6 but i can't import it into my project in visual code studio

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code, deep-learning

I installed tensorflow in Python 3.6.4 but i cannot import it into my project in Visual code studio
the error is (  ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable)
How i can solve this problem please ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a new environment first and the install any lower version of tensorflow(1.14). If Visual studios and its build tools are installed correctly then it will work for sure.